# How can I deploy my meteor app to digital ocean?

Tags: node.js, meteor, github, deployment, digital-ocean

I am building an app on the Meteor platform, and my app repository is saved on Github. My server is Digital Ocean.  I am trying to deploy commits made in Github to my remote server (website) without success. I tried three approaches, outlined below:

**1.** I tried executing "git pull" in SSH, but after receiving the message " * branch HEAD -> FETCH_HEAD Already up-to-date" the website remained unchanged.

**2.** I tried running "mupx", which many recommend for use with Meteor, but I received an error message "Verifying deployment: FAILED".

```
x Verifying deployment: FAILED

    -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
    npm@2, which has some small
    npm WARN deprecated backwards-incompatible changes made to `npm run-script` and
    npm WARN deprecated semver behavior.
    npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
    npm ERR! Failed to parse json
    npm ERR! Unexpected end of input
    npm ERR! File: /bundle/bundle/programs/server/package.json
    npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
    npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
    npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

    npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-43-generic
    npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "i"
    npm ERR! cwd /bundle/bundle/programs/server
    npm ERR! node -v v0.10.43
    npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.29
    npm ERR! file /bundle/bundle/programs/server/package.json
    npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm-debug.log
    npm ERR! not ok code 0

    => Redeploying previous version of the app

    -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------

    To see more logs type 'mup logs --tail=50'

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**3.** I even tried doing "git pull" directly into the Digital Ocean server terminal, but once again received the message " * branch HEAD -> FETCH_HEAD, Already up-to-date. ", once again without any updates to the website.

Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Well, is your package.json valid json?

Comment: It looks like your package.json isn't correct. If you post it here (edit your answer to add it), then we can see the problem

Comment: Can you list all the steps you tried to build your app and deploy onto the server? It looks like a problem in the build process